# How to set date time formatting

Tags: angular, typescript, time

How to get this format of time from the angular2 typescript?

```
2016-9-25T05:10:04.106Z
```

I tried googling could not find a clean way of doing it.

This way in TS gives the fallowing outputs,

```
Date.now();    //1474804051687 timestamp
new Date;      //Sun Sep 25 2016 17:14:45 GMT+0530
```

In JS we can get that format by

```
new Date;      //2016-9-25T05:10:04.106Z
```

What am i missing,Can anyone guide me to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a date object and call `toISOString()` method on date object
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can directly use in-bulit date filter just like in angular 1.X version

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Ref:
https://auth0.com/blog/angular2-series-working-with-pipes/

hope this helps :)